# TableViewCell editing symbols – can I change color?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a TableView with cells, for which I've enabled "delete" editing and "move" editing.

For deleting I'm using:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool)
```

and for moving I'm using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
```

Because of the colors I'm using for the backgroundColor of my cells I'm finding it very difficult to see the little move "hashmark" symbols. (see image)

[image]

My question:
Is it possible to change the color of that symbol?
I have not been able to find any information on configuring the appearance of the hashmark. (I did find reference to UITableViewCell property "editingAccessoryView" but I am hoping there is a simpler way than having to create an additional view and try to match the look of the default, when I only want to change its color.)

Comment: Thanks. The most recent answer to that post does come close (It replaces the default image when it first appears, but shifts back to the default image once touched.) I suspect I can make it work, though. I will continue working the problem.

Comment: Try changing it in `willDisplay`.

Comment: That's where I tried it. Goes away when touched.